# ASP.NET Core - Scaffold Identity like MVC

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have created a Web Application MVC project with Individuals User Accounts authentication.

Afterwards I created a custom UserIdentity. I am trying to change the default "Register" view of Identity adding my new fields, however I only managed to scaffold new pages as Razor Pages.

My question is: Is it possible to scaffold these new views in some structure like MVC? I would not like to mix MVC with Razor Pages at all.

If this is not possible, is there any way to creating a controller that overrides the default behavior (Identity/Account/Register for example)?

Comment: "I would not like to mix MVC with Razor Pages" - why not?  They don't conflict. In fact, Razor Pages _is_ (built on top of) MVC.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For anyone that wants to "scaffold" identity on MVC, I recommend the following approach:

Go to the official identity ASP.net Github Repository (https://github.com/aspnet/Identity) and download it. Open the solution and search for the IdentitySample.Mvc project. Copy the necessary files to your project.

**Important Note:** Don't forget to change the namespace on the added files since they belong to a different project.

Answer (score 13):

No, it is not possible. The Identity team decided to switch to Razor Pages for the default UI, and now that is all there is. If you like, you can manually create controllers and views, referencing code from the scaffolded Razor Pages to create the same thing in MVC, but that is on you. There is no automatic way to do so.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing now as the PM said that "it will confuse other developers" if we have MVC everywhere, onion architecture, and suddenly all the Identity stuff is in Razor pages, all logic in there as well. I get his point to be fair, it just looks and feels "messy"

Comment: I used to have a bad opinion of Razor Pages, but they've grown on me. They have a very limited usage scenario, but they cannot be beat in that scenario: basically simple CRUD and mostly static pages with data. They're entirely self-contained, and extremely easy to comprehend as a result. Need to change something in the Foo edit page? Go to to FooEdit Razor Page. Done. I initially tried to rework identity into an MVC structure, but then realized the Razor Page version is much easier to use and maintain.

Comment: Does it not bother you that (if that's the case) the rest of the project follows some strict design pattern, the Identity or any other Razor based part "stands out" ? I'm genuinely curious as I am going pretty crazy trying to follow some pattern and Microsoft throws a wrench into it :) My Core project should not have the dependency on ASP at all, but it now has to as ApplicationUser has to extend IdentityUser and thus requiring the dependency. Should I just not care and carry on?

Comment: Lot to unwrap there. Honestly, I'd say the MVC pattern is pretty much going away. There's too many moving parts, and frankly, Microsoft never did it well to begin with. Most websites can be built entirely with Razor Pages. API endpoints remain MVC, technically, but there's not really a V in that equation. For more advanced application requirements, Razor Components/Blazor are the ticket. That or traditional client-side frameworks like Angular. In any case, there's no MVC. I honestly can't think of a good use case for a pure MVC style setup.

Comment: I want MVC version of Identity